# Android's VirtualDisplay not update when screen not changes

Tags: android

Now I'm working on android screen broadcasting app.

I try to implement screen capture with VirtualDisplay and broadcasting with RTMP, I got problem when calling dequeueOutputBuffer() while current frame have not changes from old frame it will always return as MediaCodec.INFO_TRY_AGAIN_LATER, I try to keep latest frame data to use when no buffer available but it's not able to use.

Don't know how I should do, You can see my project at https://github.com/insthync/AndroidSimpleScreenRTMP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have to set KEY_REPEAT_PREVIOUS_FRAME_AFTER [Info](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaFormat.html)

Comment: Hi, I try to use this source code but it didn't work. is it work for you?